# Using retained fragment causes error inflating SupportMapFragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-maps-v2

My maps was working until I added a RetainedFragment from this tutorial ["Handling The Change"](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange).

The error occurs when inflating the layout that contains a fragment with the class *com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment*:

**PlaceholderFragment in SplashScreenActivity.java**

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_splash_screen, container, false);
```

**res/layout/fragment_splash_screen.xml**

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/app_search_map_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

Error:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class fragment
```

Complete stack:

```
03-25 10:16:51.681: I/Process(31941): Sending signal. PID: 31941 SIG: 9
03-25 10:17:00.141: E/Trace(32468): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
03-25 10:17:00.381: D/AndroidRuntime(32468): Shutting down VM
03-25 10:17:00.381: W/dalvikvm(32468): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4184c7d0)
03-25 10:17:00.401: E/AndroidRuntime(32468): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-25 10:17:00.401: E/AndroidRuntime(32468): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{br.com.ericksprengel.piz/br.com.ericksprengel.supportmapfragmentvsretainedfragment.SplashScreenActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class fragment
03-25 10:17:00.401: E/AndroidRuntime(32468):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2115)
03-25 10:17:00.401: E/AndroidRuntime(32468):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2153)
03-25 10:17:00.401: E/AndroidRuntime(32468):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:137)
03-25 10:17:00.401: E/AndroidRuntime(32468):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1246)
03-25 10:17:00.401: E/AndroidRuntime(32468):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-25 10:17:00.401: E/AndroidRuntime(32468):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-25 10:17:00.401: E/AndroidRuntime(32468):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5031)
03-25 10:17:00.401: E/AndroidRuntime(32468):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-25 10:17:00.401: E/AndroidRuntime(32468):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-25 10:17:00.401: E/AndroidRuntime(32468):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
03-25 10:17:00.401: E/AndroidRuntime(32468):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
03-25 10:17:00.401: E/AndroidRuntime(32468):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-25 10:17:00.401: E/AndroidRuntime(32468): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class fragment
03-25 10:17:00.401: E/AndroidRuntime(32468):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
03-25 10:17:00.401: E/AndroidRuntime(32468):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
03-25 10:17:00.401: E/AndroidRuntime(32468):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
03-25 10:17:00.401: E/AndroidRuntime(32468):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
03-25 10:17:00.401: E/AndroidRuntime(32468):    at br.com.ericksprengel.supportmapfragmentvsretainedfragment.SplashScreenActivity$PlaceholderFragment.onCreateView(SplashScreenActivity.java:72)
03-25 10:17:00.401: E/AndroidRuntime(32468):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
03-25 10:17:00.401: E/AndroidRuntime(32468):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
03-25 10:17:00.401: E/AndroidRuntime(32468):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
03-25 10:17:00.401: E/AndroidRuntime(32468):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
03-25 10:17:00.401: E/AndroidRuntime(32468):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
03-25 10:17:00.401: E/AndroidRuntime(32468):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:570)
03-25 10:17:00.401: E/AndroidRuntime(32468):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1163)
03-25 10:17:00.401: E/AndroidRuntime(32468):    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5068)
03-25 10:17:00.401: E/AndroidRuntime(32468):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2088)
03-25 10:17:00.401: E/AndroidRuntime(32468):    ... 11 more
03-25 10:17:00.401: E/AndroidRuntime(32468): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment did not create a view.
03-25 10:17:00.401: E/AndroidRuntime(32468):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:314)
03-25 10:17:00.401: E/AndroidRuntime(32468):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:676)
03-25 10:17:00.401: E/AndroidRuntime(32468):    ... 24 more
```

I have no ideia what's the relation between RetainedFragment vs SupportMapFragment, but this error occurs only when I use RetainedFragment.

```
// find the retained fragment on activity restarts
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
dataFragment = (RetainedFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag("data");

// create the fragment and data the first time
if (dataFragment == null) {
    // add the fragment
    dataFragment = new RetainedFragment();
    fm.beginTransaction().add(dataFragment, "data").commit();
}
```

The app does't crash if I remove this line

```
fm.beginTransaction().add(dataFragment, "data").commit();
```

I have created a simple project that contains a simple Activity with a simple layout with the SupportMapFragment and a RetainedFragment.

**Simple Project:**
https://github.com/ericksprengel/support-map-fragment-vs-retained-fragment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how this relates to your RetainedFragment, that is odd.

But it looks like your problem is related to [Having an issue with GoogleMap v2 crashing app on orientation change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19166504/having-an-issue-with-googlemap-v2-crashing-app-on-orientation-change).

You are creating a placeholder fragment, then loading a child fragment from xml. It looks like this does not work, and child fragments can only be added dynamically. Try that and see if it fixes your issue.

Comment: It worked for me.!!
[see the commit here](https://github.com/ericksprengel/support-map-fragment-vs-retained-fragment/commit/6e9f61a728da2e2663d38ec8da6c7188379ea645)

Comment: It's too odd, because I can inflate the fragment if I'm not using RetainedFragment. I can't understand this relation. =O