# Google maps SupportMapFragment error in Fragment

Tags: android, google-maps

Old version app use `MapView`.I changed `SupportMapFragment` error. I know how to solve this problem.

> Process: com.test.app, PID: 7847
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error
>   inflating class fragment

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<fragment
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

fragment

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback,
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    LocationListener {

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, null);

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    buildGoogleApiClient();


    return rootView;
}
```

build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.0'
    compile 'se.emilsjolander:stickylistheaders:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0'
//compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.0'


 }
```

Comment: Apply context to your fragment pointing to the correct activity using the tools:context attribute

Comment: I have used but did not work @Bradley Wilson

Comment: use getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager() instead

Comment: I have checked getActivity() and the new error java.lang.NullPointerException mapFragment

Comment: you included findFragmentById(R.id.map) aswell, right? so it should be getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);?

Comment: Yes, mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138321/discussion-between-bradley-wilson-and-roma-darvish).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved that problem as this way.

```
if (view != null) {
   ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
   if (parent != null)
      parent.removeView(view);
}

try {
     view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_partners_map, container, false);
} catch (InflateException e) {
}
```

First time I'm check that, is the Fragments parents view exists, then I recreate the parent, else I create it.

Comment: I believe your error was caused by the fact your were inflating nested fragments. I think the appropriate solution (and not a workaround) will be replacing the `<fragment>` with `<framelayout>` as shown here [link]https://stackoverflow.com/a/19167009/5477548. If that works for you, go upvote him.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

SupportMapFragment mapFragment;

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-33.852, 151.211);
    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                         @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_fragment, container, false);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```

}

```
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/content_frame"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_weight="1">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I have it set up

**XML**:

```
 <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" />
```

Code:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;


SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.mapView);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

Have your `fragment` Implement `OnMapReadyCallback` (e.g. `extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback`) and copy this method:

```
@Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        map.setTrafficEnabled(false);
        map.setIndoorEnabled(false);
        map.setBuildingsEnabled(false);
        map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        LatLng wotw = new LatLng(getLat(), getLong());
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(wotw)
                .title("Walk of the Week"));
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(wotw));
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15.0f));
    }
```

Make sure you have your API key in your `Manifest` too:

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="API_KEY_HERE"/>
```

and the corresponding permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add to the dependency the following:

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.1'

Then click Sync Now.